# How can I use clippath to customise a container as shown in the image below?

Tags: flutter, flutter-clippath

[image]

How can i do this in flutter, need help

I try this one but it did'nt work, it make only two arcs but i need four, if some one can help me to make this design.How can I make the above design, I tried but without success, I need help to make it in flutter with CustomClippath or CustomPaint widgets, Understanding how it works also escapes me a little, as does positioning a voluntary point on any side of my container and making a deformation there.

```
class CustomlipperTest extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  CustomlipperTest({this.radius = 38});
  final double radius;
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path();
    final double v = radius * 2;
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(180),
      degreeToRadians(90),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * 0.4, 0, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(270),
      degreeToRadians(90),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * 0.4 + 36, -v / 2, 16, v - 10),
      degreeToRadians(160),
      degreeToRadians(-120),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .4 + 50, 0, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(200),
      degreeToRadians(70),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * 0.8, 0, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(270),
      degreeToRadians(70),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * 0.8 + 36, -v / 2, 16, v - 10),
      degreeToRadians(160),
      degreeToRadians(-140),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .8 + 50, 0, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(200),
      degreeToRadians(70),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .8 + 50, 0, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(200),
      degreeToRadians(70),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .8 + 50, 0, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(200),
      degreeToRadians(70),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .4 + 50, size.height, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(90),
      degreeToRadians(90),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .4 + 36, size.height - v / 2 + 10, 16, v - 10),
      degreeToRadians(-22),
      degreeToRadians(-130),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .4, size.height - radius, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(0),
      degreeToRadians(100),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .8 + 50, size.height - radius, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(90),
      degreeToRadians(90),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .8 + 36, size.height - v / 2 + 10, 16, v - 10),
      degreeToRadians(-22),
      degreeToRadians(-130),
      false,
    );

    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .8, size.height - radius, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(0),
      degreeToRadians(100),
      false,
    );
    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, size.height - radius, radius, radius),
      degreeToRadians(90),
      degreeToRadians(90),
      false,
    );
    path.lineTo(0, radius);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) => true;

  double degreeToRadians(double degree) {
    final double redian = (math.pi / 180) * degree;
    return redian;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is just the needless repetition of the tags, which shouldn't even be in the title at all. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].